# Missing a chunk of posts after a database backup

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, backup

I switched my website over to a different host and domain name recently, and restored the backup I'd taken from the old website, and changed the database name and domain name and everything, so it's working perfectly....EXCEPT I'm missing a chunk of posts in my wordpress posts table from ID 4976 to 5013. When I open the backup in my text editor, I can see them in there, but when I try to put them in to SQL (I have mySQL and cPanel), I get errors about the primary key being duplicated. What's wrong and how do I restore my posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly duplicating these posts as no two rows can have the same primary key.

Would recommend running this query:

SELECT * FROM (your table name) WHERE (ID) BETWEEN 4976 AND 5013;

To see if the posts exist. If so, then I wouldn't worry about this error.